# Matlab visualization

Tags: matlab-figure

I used this link to walk through FDTD code and write it for myself to practice.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7hJAhKp2d8

This is the code that I wrote (its not verbatim, but extremely similar). When I run the program, I am told that "Field amplitude is too small to visualize properly." I don't understand why. As far as I understand Matlab (I'm very new to it), I am scaling the graph on my own. There is a function called draw1d that is in a protected file here:  http://emlab.utep.edu/ee5390fdtd.htm

How should I fix this?

```
    %FDTD1D

%Initailize
close all;
clc;
clear all;

% Units

meters = 1;
seconds = 1;

%Fundamental constants
c0 = 3e8 * meters/seconds;
e0 = 8.85e-12 * 1/meters;
u0 = 1.26e-6 * 1/meters;

%Figure Window
figure('Color', 'b');

%%%%%%%
%% FUNAMENTAL CONSTANTS
%%%%%%%%%
%Simple parameters
dz = 5 * meters;
Nz = 200;
dt = 1e-3 * seconds;
STEPS = 1000;

%%%%%%%
%% BUILD DEVICE ON GRID
%%%%%%%%%

%Grid Device - let it be air
ER = ones(1, Nz);
UR = ones(1, Nz);

%%%%%%%
%% Initialize FDTD Parameters
%%%%%%%%%

%Initialize Vectors
mEy = (c0*dt)./ER; %unique update coefficient for each place on the grid
mHx = (c0*dt)./UR; %unique update coefficent again

%%%%%%%
%% Initialize Fields
%%%%%%%%%

%Initialize Fields
Ey = zeros(1, Nz);
Hx = zeros(1, Nz);

%%%%%%%
%% IFDTD LOOP  ANALYSIS
%%%%%%%%%

    %Actually doing FDTD
    for T = 1 : STEPS 

    %Update H from E
    for nz  = 1 : Nz - 1
       Hx(nz) = Hx(nz) + mHx(nz)*(Ey(nz+1) - Ey(nz))/dz;
     end

    Hx(Nz) = Hx(Nz) + mHx(Nz)*(0 - Ey(Nz))/dz;


    %Update E from H

    Ey(1) = Ey(1) + mEy(1) * ( Hx(1) - 0 )/dz;
    for nz = 2 : Nz
        Ey(nz) = Ey(nz) + mEy(nz) * ( Hx(nz) - Hx(nz-1) )/dz;
    end 

    %Show Status

    if ~mod(T, 10)

        draw1d(ER, Ey, Hx, dz);
        xlim([dz Nz*dz]);
        xlabel('z');
        title(['Field at step ' num2str(T) ' of ' num2str(STEPS)]);
    end


end
```